# Performance report for myweb site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive, gtmetrix

I am developing a web site and it is almost hosted. Due to low page loading speed I have tested my web site page speed performance via [gtmetrix.com](https://gtmetrix.com/). So its report generate two issues as the reasons for low page speed.

**Issues that affect to page loading speed**

- **Combine images using CSS sprites**

  *The following images served from abc.com should be combined into as few images as possible using CSS sprites.*

  Combining images into as few files as possible using CSS sprites reduces the number of round-trips and delays in
  downloading other resources, reduces request overhead, and can reduce
  the total number of bytes downloaded by a web page.
- **Specify image dimensions**

  *The following image(s) are missing width and/or height attributes.*

  Specifying a width and height for all images allows for faster rendering by eliminating the need for unnecessary reflows
  and repaints.

  **...abc.com/banner.jpg (Dimensions: 512 x 33)**

This is the waterfall

[image: waterfall]
[image: image 02]

## I'am OK with CSS sprites

.

#### System specifications

- Laravel 5.5
- Bootstrap 3.3.7

To images to be responsive I have added bootstrap class

`<img src="../abc.com/banner.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" id="banner">` .

So I added custom CSS to image via using `id="banner"`

```
#banner{
  min-width : 512px ;
  min-height: 33px ;
}
```

**My problem is when I add that custom css web site lost its Responsiveness.**

So could anyone please help on this. I want to specify dimensions for images and also it should be responsive. Because this affect to my web site speed.

Comment: It's odd that one image would cause your website to load slow. Unless it's massive and hasn't been optimised. It would be interesting to see a waterfall chart of your site loading.

Comment: @ngearing actually this is not about one image. Landing page of this site containe more than 100 images. Ill update my question with waterfall chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer this question.

Try to change your following code:

```
<img src="../abc.com/banner.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" id="banner">
```

Into:

```
<img src="../abc.com/banner.jpg" width="512" height="33" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
```

You need to remove the id "id="banner"" to re-enable your banner responsiveness.

You can check up my blog http://qibug.com to see the real world example to resolve issue "Specify image dimensions"; I was specified my images dimensions without sacrificing their responsiveness. Try opening the post page to check the same thing on the feature image.

I hope you'll be okay with my answer.

Comment: thanks for consuming your valuble time on this. Ill check this and if it slove my issue Ill make it as an answer. Once again thanks